# Elasticsearch: What happens if one of the bulk update fails ?

Tags: elasticsearch, bulkupdate

What happens if I make a bulk update with Elasticsearch with 100 different documents. And just one of them fails. 
Will all of them fail? or just that one?

Answer (score 1):

A single failing request won't be failing the whole bulk. you can examine the response of the bulk update api and check if any failure

Comment: See also the [Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#bulk-api-response-body): _The success or failure of an individual operation does not affect other operations in the request._

Answer (score 0):

Items in a bulk request are independent of each other, meaning that a failure of one will not stop subsequent items from being processed. Therefore if any items fail the bulk request will be a partial success. (Any item in a bulk request could individually fail for the same reasons that a single index request could fail. These reasons include but are not limited to version conflicts, not enough shard copies available to satisfy the write consistency setting, mapping conflicts, etc.)